# Cuales son la condiciones en mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo una duda, ya no me acuerdo de las condiciones en Mysql, estoy haciendo consultas con Inner join y palabras reservadas.

```
SELECT (Nombre_empresa) FROM (empresa)
INNER JOIN (lucha) 
ON (id_empresa=id_lucha)
WHERE condiciones_para_cualquier_campo_de_cualquier_tabla
```

Gracias! espero una respuesta.

Comment: y cual es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

InnerJoin buscara los valores en comun que tienen 2 tablas segun el filtro "where"(opcional) que indiques, lo que debes de tomar en consideración es que las tablas a las cuales hagas referencias deben de poseer valores que COINCIDAN, ejemplo.

```
SELECT nombre_columnas
FROM tabla1
INNER JOIN tabla2 ON tabla1.nombre_columnas = tabla2.nombre_columnas
WHERE tabla2.nombre_columnas='gabriel'
```

Desconozco si esa era tu duda, si no era expecifica cual es tu inconveniente para así poderte ayudar

Comment: se agradece tu apoyo, pero deberíamos esperar a que la pregunta del OP sea clara pues no termina de explicar que es lo que no puede hacer, precisamente como lo colocas al final de tu respuesta no sabemos si es esa la duda o alguna otra